# Javascript won't load on links with jQuery mobile included

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery-mobile, flask

Edit: While trying to find the solution, the topic has changed a bit - TL;DR: See the answer. For all interested in the development of the topic, go on ;-)

The title might be confusing, but I don't know how to put it in better words - let's say I have a simple view function:

```
@app.route('/chart')
def chart():

return render_template('chart.html')
```

If I open now directly this view in the browser, via "http://localhost:5000/start", it works perfectly fine - the javascript stuff works as expected (drawing a chart, using a slider to call different views etc.).

However, using a link from an other template does not work, e.g. I have a root view:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

and inside of this `index.html` a link directed to '/chart':

```
 <a href="{{ url_for('chart') }}">Chart</a>
```

Now, pressing that link, it loads my template, I can see the basic html stuff, but the javascript code doesn't load/start at all (also the source code received by the browser is proper). In both scenarios the server receives the same command:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2015 10:48:18] "GET /chart HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But only if I open it directly in the browser it works as expected.

Is there something wrong with my link/redirect?

Edit: I found the one single line which causes the problems: In my `index.html` I'm loading jQuery mobile:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Removing this line, everything works as expected - but of course I do wan't to have it included, why and how can this influence the link behavior?

Comment: Is the JS in the `chart.html` template or a separate file? If you open your browser's developer tools can you see the JS code?

Comment: Mixed, some custom code inside, some libraries external. When I press the link, the devTools only show one get method receiving the chart.html als text/html and nothing more. If I open /chart directly in the browser, it loads all the javascript files/requests. However, I found the single line in index.html which ruins everything:  
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>`  
I'll edit my question now, I have no idea why this line is responsible.

Comment: I'm one step further now: The problem occurs because jQuery mobile doesn't do a full page refresh on links normally, so I'd have to add `data-ajax="false"` to the link. It works this way, but it would be of course interesting if it can work without a full page request as well.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about jQuery mobile, so I'm not sure how much help I can be. Glad you're getting somewhere at least though.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the core of my problem now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, jQuery uses Ajax to handle page requests. This allows for smooth transition between pages (without the page refresh feel), but it also means that only the body of the requested page will be loaded - and therefore no javascript libraries included in the header.

Therefore all necessary javascript has to be included in the header of the original site, or instead a page request has to be done without ajax, using the `data-ajax="false"`attribute. This will do a real page refresh, without ajax transition.

For more information read [this](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/).

Comment: Thanks for posting your own answer for future users. It might be worth changing the title of the post as well, if you can, so that it's more like to be found in Google searches.